# How add css class to woocommerce category from admin panel?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[screenshot from photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QffE9.jpg)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QffE9.jpg)

hello,
I need a way to add css style for the category of woocommerce from admin panel.

I need to add input for writing css class, that are assigned to this category in the code.

Help me find a way to solve or may be plug-in.

Thank you

Sorry for my English

Comment: Why can't you use the category class?

Comment: I need to write css class that the client will use for the categories created by him. These categories will be different design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good [tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/how-to-use-term-meta-data-in-wordpress/) on how to do this. I've adapted the code, but haven't tested it so be wary of typos.

**Note:** WordPress 4.4 is required for the following to work.

```
// add the fields when the term is created
add_action( 'product_cat_add_form_fields', 'add_product_cat_class_field', 10, 2 );

function add_product_cat_class_field($taxonomy) {
    global $feature_groups;
    ?><div class="form-field term-group">
        <label for="featuret-group"><?php _e('Custom CSS Class', 'my_plugin'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="postform" id="custom-class" name="custom-class" value="">
        </select>
    </div><?php
}

// add the fields when the term is being edited
add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'edit_product_cat_class_field', 10, 2 );

function edit_product_cat_class_field( $term, $taxonomy ){

    global $feature_groups;

    // get current group
    $class = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'custom-class', true );

    ?><tr class="form-field term-group-wrap">
        <th scope="row"><label for="feature-group"><?php _e( 'Feature Group', 'my_plugin' ); ?></label></th>
        <td><input type="text" class="postform" id="custom-class" name="custom-class" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $class ); ?>"></td>
    </tr><?php
}

// save the term meta
add_action( 'created_product_cat', 'save_product_cat_class_meta', 10, 2 );

function save_product_cat_class_meta( $term_id, $tt_id ){
    if( isset( $_POST['custom-class'] ) && '' !== $_POST['custom-class'] ){
        $class = sanitize_slug( $_POST['custom-class'] );
        add_term_meta( $term_id, 'custom-class', $class, true );
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! but  i have error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_term_meta()

line: // get current group

Comment: [`get_term_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/) was introduced in WordPress 4.4, so you might need to upgrade.

Comment: One moe question: how i can add body_class from meta_value?
It's not worked:

function lalka_custom_taxonomy_in_body_class( $classes ){
  if( is_singular() )
  {
    $custom_terms = get_term_meta($meta_id, 'custom-class', true );
    if ($custom_terms) {
      foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
        $classes[] = 'custom-tax-' . $custom_term->slug;
      }
    }
  }
  return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'body_class', 'lalka_custom_taxonomy_in_body_class' );

Comment: How are you defining `$meta_id`? But please edit your question because code is impossible to read in the comments.

Comment: sorry, i'm write here - [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/220578/how-add-body-class-from-wp-termmeta)